# GitHub: What is the effect of the "Ask admin for access" in Pull Requests?

Tags: github, repository

I noticed that on a pull request not by oneself, and not in a repo where you have access under *Reviewers* there is this notice:

> Still in progress? Learn about draft PRs  (i)

Clicking on "Learn about draft PRs  (i)" opens pop-up that explains draft PRs [1].
What does not really fit in there for me is a button: **Ask admin for access**?

So far I've found no explanation what this button does, what is the purpose of this button and what is the scope of *access* that could be granted?

---

[1]

> Try draft pull requests
> Open an in-progress pull request without asking for formal review or risking an unwanted merge. When you're ready for code review, you can mark your draft pull request as ready for review, which will request reviews from any code owners.